# Gitlab CI CD - несколько runner в одном контейнере

Tags: docker, непрерывная-интеграция

есть запущенный Runner в контейнере

```
localadmin@ubuntu:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
357e6201c012        gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest   "/usr/bin/dumb-ini..."   8 hours ago         Up 12 minutes                           gitlab-runner
localadmin@ubuntu:~$
```

Этой командой:

> docker exec -it gitlab-runner gitlab-runner register

Зарегистрировал новый runner в вышеупомянутом контейнере

Все ок, runner работает.
Теперь нужно присоединить к нему еще один runner (в этот же контейнер)

выполняю команду:

> docker exec -it gitlab-runner gitlab-runner register

В config.toml ничего не меняется, но на gitlab.com появляется запись о том что Runner создался и доступен.

Добавил в config.tom вручную запись о втором ruuner

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "deployer"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "TOKEN"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "backend:api"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
[[runners]]
  name = "deployer"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "TOKEN"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "frontend:frontend"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
```

Но при попытке деплоя из гитлаб, появляется следующая ошибка

> $ docker build -t image-frontend . Cannot connect to the Docker
>   daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
>   ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так.

Comment: обычно docker нужно запускать от имени супервользователья. нужно проверить имеет ли юзер доступ и запущен ли докер

Comment: в sudo ALL не хватает привилегий?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что с тем с кем я работал, запускал руне из под рута, а я из другого пользователя...

Comment: А это в моем случае и есть исчерпывающий ответ